# Can 7 AKE containers adjacent to each other be securely locked in a 777-300ER's aft cargo bin?

Tags: safety, ground-operations, boeing-777, cargo

Is it possible to securely lock 7 [AKE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_load_device#Types) (LD3) containers adjacent to each other in a Boeing 777-300ER's aft cargo bin from position 31 to 41 (41 included)?

According to my experience it's impossible to securely lock 7 AKE containers adjacent to each other if a partial load stop is raised between the containers.

If a ULD lock does not get raised between containers, then it is OK to lock containers using only an end-stop at the beginning of position 31 and raising the lateral guide located at the end of position 41 (between positions 41 & 42), but I'm a bit unsure of using such a combination and find this unsafe because there are only two ULD locks that secures 7 sequential containers.

Could somebody confirm whether is it safe to do so and/or can give detailed information on B777-300 ER cargo hold loading configurations, ULD locks and ULD loading rules?

Comment: The 777-300 ER weight and balance control and loading manual, D043W530-XXX1  has some of what you want.

Comment: @FreeMan: I've replaced it with a Wikipedia link.

Comment: @ymb1 thank you good sir! Coffee wasn't working this morning and I didn't see one.

Comment: This seems awfully specific for an "I'm just curious about how airlines do this stuff" question, and "some guy on the internet told me it was fine" isn't good enough if you're loading an actual plane.